# Skipping installation of already existing fonts in nullsoft SIS

Tags: fonts, nsis

I'm using Nullsoft SIS and I want to know how to detect whether certain fonts are already installed on the system.
So I can skip their installation if they are found.
I want to install the fonts only in case they are not installed already.

Answer (score 3):

Use *IfFileExists* to check existence of certain file.

```
  IfFileExists "$FONTS\arial.ttf" Continue InstallFont

InstallFont:
  SetOutPath "$FONTS"
  File "arial.ttf"

Continue:
  # Continue in installation...
```

If you have multiple files then use nsArray for storing file names and {For} loop to iterate all files.